# Set Oracle SQL Developer auto complete suggestions to lower case

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.0.3.16, Build MAIN-16.84. My problem is that when I start typing the table name (ex: employees, departments), the auto complete appears with upper case (ex: EMPLOYEES, DEPARTMENTS) [ScreenShot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B45M2diwtWsGUkZFcVBqOVFZV2M/view?usp=sharing) and without selecting any of the suggestions. It is very annoying to see suggestions like

> LAST_VALUE or LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) or LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) - SYSDATE

when you are typing

> SELECT last_name FROM employees

. At the university we use an older version of this program and there I get auto correct hints in lower case and the first one is always selected (so pressing the Tab accepts the completion). This forces me to press the down arrow and Enter or Tab to accept the completion.

My perfect code would be something like keyword in Upper Case and table names is lower case, +the first completion suggestion should be always selected.

Is there a setting for this or this is a default feature of that older version, while the newer one lacks it? Or maybe this comes from the Oracle Express Edition? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your version 2.1 we have an option to go to

**Tools> Preferences>Code Editor> completion Insight**

and Uncheck the option **Change Case as you type**

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: Sort of, but not 100% what I wanted. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Is there a way to modify what items show? I have never used 'Select * bulk' but this is the default option after I type 'Select *'

Comment: or you can use F6 as a short-key